# How can this object be appended to a specific tile on an isometric map?

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

I have an isometric map that has selectable tiles. The map is formed by a matrix such as `$('div').gameMap({map:[[{"tile":"tile_0","object":"anObjectOnTile"},{"tile":"tile_3","object":""}], [{...}]],mapsize:3});` If the tile has something within the `object:""`, then that tile has that object (in my case, an image of an oil derrick) on top of that tile.

There is a Place button which when clicked should place an oil derrick object on top of the currently selected tile.

However, I have run into two problems:

1. Knowing which tile is currently selected
2. Adding a single oil derrick

At first I wanted to figure a way to modify the map's matrix to insert the object's name (`oilDerrick`) into the tile's object parameter, but now I think the better solution would be to append the `oilDerrick` to the tile. I can't figure out how to append to the particular tile and not *every* tile.

I've got the code set up to look at and play with: http://jsfiddle.net/briz/jdhPW/13/

There's an oilDerrick object set up in the map's matrix for you to view, which can be removed by deleting the word `oilDerrick` in the matrix

I played with `$(".tile").append($('.oilDerrick'));` though I knew that would append to every tile. But I simply do not know enough about appending yet to figure out how to limit it to a single instance.

Each tile has a unique ID. I also tried this in order to add an oilDerrick to a certain tile:

```
$("#placeButton").click(function()
{
      for (var y in config.map) 
      {
            for (var x in config.map[y]) 
            {
                document.getElementById(obj.attr('id') + '_tile_' + x + '_' +y).appendChild(".oilDerrick");
            }
      }
}
```

But this came to no avail as well. I think I'm heading in the right direction though? Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I did some modifications](http://jsfiddle.net/orlleite/jdhPW/15/).

There a little mess in your code. For example, your using jquery but there is a lot of direct DOM manipulation.

```
.style.background = ...
// should be
.css("background",...)
```

And the most important:

```
document.getElementById(...)
// should be
$("#...")
```

Easier, don't you think? Then, the problem is simple solved by creating a var `currentTile` and when the user select one tile, it save it. When click in 'place', `$(currentTile).append($('.oilDerrick'));` And the oil derrick move to where to selected tile.

Anyway, more details you can see in the link.

Comment: Awesome, you both made the code better and solved the problem! Genius! Now the only question is why the derrick cannot be "re-appended" again after you remove it...

Comment: I thought it was the idea. There is a flag var `drillPlaced = true`, just comment it in `$("#placeButton").click(function()...`

Comment: Here's a follow-up question about the seeming append problem, if you want to take a look :-) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8189579/why-cant-i-append-an-element-remove-it-then-append-the-same-element-a-second